# How to use Crystal Report in FsXaml

Tags: f#, fsxaml

I have added `Report.rpt` and a `Report.fs` file by right clicking on project in Solution Explorer. In `Report.fs` I have declared two Type `Report()` and `CachedReport()`, which in C# are generated automatically, and added F# code in it by looking at a `.cs` file which CrystalReport generated in a C# WPF Projet. In Xaml I have

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ShowReport}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ViewReport}" Content="Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

and in ViewModel

```
let doc = new CrystalReportsViewer()
let setSource() = 
    let rpt = new Report()
    rpt.Load("~/Report.rpt")
    doc.ViewerCore.ReportSource <- rpt
member x.ShowReport =  doc
member x.ViewReport = self.Factory.CommandSync(setSource)
```

When I start the application I can see CrystalReport Viewer in place. If I click the button Application closes automatically.

If I double click on `Report.rpt` a dialog box pops up and says `This document could not be opened`.

How can I use it in F# WPF? 
Is there any other reporting tool for F# WPF?

Comment: not sure I understand what exactly is the problem

Comment: @FoggyFinder what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to build a C# Class Library with a Report as embedded resource, add the assembly in F# reference and write ...

```
let doc = new CrystalReportsViewer()
let setSource() = 
    let rpt = new MyCsClass.CrystalReport1()
    ....
    doc.ViewerCore.ReportSource <- rpt
```

thats all!